# Using WebGL through WKWebview

Tags: ios, three.js, webgl, wkwebview

How can I assure that running a three.js based 3D scene through WKWebview can have maximum performance? I do not want to be limited to browser-based resource constraints and make sure I can use an iPhone's GPU and other hardware.

Comment: Sorry for not providing any value, just wanted to let you know that you aren't the only one wondering. I am wondering the same!